# iOS open source smart controller push/pop lib for uinavigationcontroller?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

I have an application where the user can push infinitely deep into views (pushing onto nav stack). At some point, there will be a memory warning. I'd like to remove view controllers from the navigation controller and dealloc them. If the user goes back to those view controllers, I'd like to recreate the view controllers and push them back into the correct position in the stack.

Is this the right way to be thinking about this problem?

Is there an open source project that does this? It doesn't seem like an uncommon issue and I'd rather not reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 2):

There was a time where you needed to make sure that calls to `viewDidLoad` and `viewDidUnload` matched properly so that memory warnings could be handled this way. Since iOS 6 this is no longer necessary.

As it says in the documentation for `viewDidUnload`:

> In iOS 5 and earlier, when a low-memory condition occurred and the
>   current view controller’s views were not needed, the system could opt
>   to call this method after the view controller’s view had been
>   released. This method was your chance to perform any final cleanup. If
>   your view controller stored separate references to the view or its
>   subviews, you could use this method to release those references. You
>   could also use this method to remove references to any objects that
>   you created to support the view but that are no longer needed now that
>   the view is gone. You would not use this method to release user data
>   or any other information that cannot be easily recreated.
>
> In iOS 6 and later, clearing references to views and other objects in
>   your view controller is unnecessary.

If you're manually keeping large objects in memory, such as image or video data, then you can override `didReceiveMemoryWarning` to release those objects where necessary.